# Android on Windows - Run as Ant Build

Tags: android, ant, project

Ok, I'm an android newbie - totally. But I am trying to run a project provided by someone else that I know works.

I'm running on a Windows install of Eclipse that seems to be working fine.

When I run this project I get a dialog box asking which Ant to Run as and  my choices are Ant Build and Ant Build with Allowed Configuration changes.

Since I don't know about Ant, I pick Ant Build and get this error: Unable to find Ant file to run.

So my question is, how to I either get rid of this requirement to have an Ant file for this project or how do I create an Ant file for this as there doesn't seem to be one included in the project, or how do I install Ant - I'm on Windows.

Please help by answering above or pointing to documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse Plugin for Android installed? That may be the problem. Here's the link: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: yes, I do have that for 4.0 and 4.1. Are there any other files I need? Do ant files have a certain extension that I can check for in the project I received? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem. I had to open the project via Window > Show > Project Explorer rather than just trying to Run .project. I think this solved it as the Ant error message did not appear when I ran from the project explorer. Thanks for responding.